# Replace part of an object with another

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects where each object has many properties (key-value pairs).

We will have many occasions where different API calls, or server-sent-events (via websockets) will return data to update some objects in the list. The difficult thing is that each different call will return only the part of the data for each object, not the full data.

The question is about the most efficient way to replace only the bits that have changed - noting that this data is used in a React application, so we need to also consider immutable consequences.

My idea was simply to match the `id` in the original data to the new data, then I would have to loop through the incoming data to find the keys, then replace the original data with that key. It seems like there might be a more efficient way to do this.

```js
let original_data = [{
    id: 1,
    value_1: 'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=1',
    value_2: 'will only change when value_2 method is called',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value_1: 'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=2',
    value_2: 'will only change when value_2 method is called',
  },
]

let replacement_data = [{
  id: 1,
  value_1: 'assume value_1 method was called for id=1',
}]

for (let i in replacement_data) {
  //get the index matched by id
  index = original_data.findIndex((x => x.id === replacement_data[i].id))

  //replace only the data that has changed
  for (var key in replacement_data[i]) {
    original_data[index][key] = replacement_data[i][key]
  }
}

console.log(original_data);
```

This does work, but if I had an event where a few thousand of these changes came in, would it be slow and is there a better way to do this either for efficiency, or a best-practice method I should be employing?

Comment: There's a few errors in your code. First off, use `for..of` to iterate through arrays, not `for..in`. You have declared `i` in the outer loop as an index (but in actuality will be a key due to `for..in`), and then declare an `i` in the function passed to `findIndex` as an element of the `original_data` array.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed that now as it was copy-pasted from my real code, then I replaced a few names of keys and ended up with a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an optimization by adding comparison with `JSON.stringify` to check if the objects are different (this will only work assuming that the order of the keys are the same)

```js
let original_data = [
  {
    id:1,
    value_1:'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=1',
    value_2:'will only change when value_2 method is called',
  },
  {
    id:2,
    value_1:'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=2',
    value_2:'will only change when value_2 method is called',
  },
];

let replacement_data = [
  {
    id:1,
    value_1:'assume value_1 method was called for id=1',
  },
  {
    id:2,
    value_2:'assume value_2 method was called for id=2',
  }
];


const modifyChanges = () => {
    replacement_data.forEach((el) => {
        const data = original_data.find(x => x.id === el.id);
        if (JSON.stringify(data) !== JSON.stringify(el)){ 
           for (const key in el){
             data[key] = el[key];
           }
        }
    });
}

modifyChanges();

console.log(original_data);
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, then it's only going to update where the incoming data's id matches an id in the original data, so it's not going to iterate through the whole original data set. In which case, since I know that in all cases the data being returned is always new and needs updating, I can remove the `stringify` bit too (since `stringify` is a slow process... I think?).

Comment: If the updated data object is always different from the original data object so yes, you can remove that condition (:

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with the references to the objects with the same `id` without iterating the array.

```js
const
    update = data => {
        const references = Object.fromEntries(original_data.map(o => [o.id, o]));
        return (id, key, value) => references[id][key] = value;
    };
    original_data = [{ id: 1, value_1: 'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=1', value_2: 'will only change when value_2 method is called' }, { id: 2, value_1: 'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=2', value_2: 'will only change when value_2 method is called' }],
    updateData = update(original_data);

updateData(1, 'value_2', 'foo');

console.log(original_data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using key-value pair and ES6, you can use [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map type, and get a bunch of operations for free. You will need to adjust your data a bit or just create some sort of loop to insert them into the map

```
let original_data = new Map();
original_data.set(1, {
    id: 1,
    value_1: 'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=1',
    value_2: 'will only change when value_2 method is called',
  });
original_data.set(2, {
  {
    id: 2,
    value_1: 'will only change when value_1 method is called for id=2',
    value_2: 'will only change when value_2 method is called',
  });
```

Then you can just use `Map.set` to update the specific data:

```
let replacement_data = [{
  id: 1,
  value_1: 'assume value_1 method was called for id=1',
}];
for(const data of replacement_data){
  original_data.set(data.id, data);
}
```